# Error installing Rails: Failed to build Gem native extension, 'lack of libraries or headers'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've been trying to get rails working but whatever I do it comes up with this error. So far I've tried to update everything, re install homebrew, and re install ruby. RVM however will not installl

```
sudo gem install rails

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--help
--clean
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in            `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block     in try_compile'
from    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:500:in    `with_werror'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
from extconf.rb:77:in `block in add_cflags'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:599:in `with_cflags'
from extconf.rb:76:in `add_cflags'
from extconf.rb:323:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you got the error

`"You have to install development tools first."`

Incase, while trying to update a bundle, you get an error `"You have to install development tools first."` on OSX ,

If you already have Xcode installed, you can still manually install the development tools via terminal:

```
 xcode-select --install
```

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your question fails to specify your development environment. Mac? If so, Have you installed the full XCode from Apple? I see that line that says "install development tools"

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up ... to help explain

it may be that you are on a mac and rails cannot find the right compiler for c headers.

just install xcode from apps store / homebrew or go to terminal ...

> $ xcode-select --install

complete the installation and agree on the licensing etc, then ...

> $ sudo gem install rails